# I have a list of comments, how to choose one by one, without repeating the same comment

Tags: python, list, random

```
def random_comment():
    with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
        comments = [line.strip() for line in f]
    comment = random.choice(comments)
    return comment
```

Comment: Don't choose them one by one, take a `random.sample(comments, number_you_want)`

Answer (score 1):

Read all the comments once (before calling random). Then in the random_comment(), chose a random comment from your list and remove it from the list.

```
all_comments = []
with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_comments.append([line.strip() for line in f])

def random_comment(all_comments):
    index = random.randint(0,len(all_comments))
    result = all_comments.pop(index)
    return result, all_comments
```

Comment: `.remove` removes by value, not by index.

Comment: This has a major drawback, though: you need to regenerate the complete list if you want to take another sample.

Comment: ```
import random
class Comments:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.comments = random.shuffel([line.strip() for line in f])
        self.position = 0
    def random_comment(self):
        comment = self.comment[self.position]
        position += 1
        return comment
myComments = Comments("file_path")
randomComment = myComments.random_comment()
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille no you don't, you return the updated list. And you take the list as parameter so you just have to pass the last returned list.

Comment: @mkrieger1 indeed, let me edit it

Comment: Yes, you do. Try it with `all_comments = ["A", "B", "C"] ; res, comm = random_comment(all_comments) ; print(res, all_comments)`. It prints `B ['A', 'C']`. You only mutate the original list that your function got as argument, and never create a new one.

Comment: i'm getting this error: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Comment: Oh ok, i thought you meant that you have to read it all again every time. You are indeed right, we should use pop instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: A 0 is missing in random.randint, it's edited.